# Ruby: why isn't the Mutex holding the lock when I use the same instance variable name?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

While debugging a thread-safety issue, I could come up with a reproducible scenario that will always result in a race condition, even tough a Mutex is being used.

Here's the class:

```rb
class TestClass

  MUTEX = Mutex.new

  class << self

    def series
      @series ||= MUTEX.synchronize { @series || build_series }
    end

    def build_series
      @series = {}
      sleep 3
      @series = { foo: "bar" }
      @series
    end

  end

end
```

Now fire up `irb` and run this:

```rb
threads = []; 10.times { threads.push(Thread.new { TestClass.series.fetch(:foo) }) }; threads.map(&:value)
```

This will error out 100% of the times:

```rb
#<Thread:0x000000011a2f7810 (pry):1 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
(pry):1:in `fetch': key not found: :foo (KeyError)
    from (pry):1:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
#<Thread:0x000000011a2f7720 (pry):1 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
(pry):1:in `fetch': key not found: :foo (KeyError)
    from (pry):1:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
#<Thread:0x000000011a2f7630 (pry):1 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
(pry):1:in `fetch': key not found: :foo (KeyError)
    from (pry):1:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
#<Thread:0x000000011a2f7540 (pry):1 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
(pry):1:in `fetch': key not found: :foo (KeyError)
    from (pry):1:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
#<Thread:0x000000011a2f7360 (pry):1 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
(pry):1:in `fetch': key not found: :foo (KeyError)
    from (pry):1:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
#<Thread:0x000000011a2f7270 (pry):1 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
(pry):1:in `fetch': key not found: :foo (KeyError)
    from (pry):1:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
#<Thread:0x000000011a2f7180 (pry):1 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
(pry):1:in `fetch': key not found: :foo (KeyError)
    from (pry):1:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
#<Thread:0x000000011a2f7090 (pry):1 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
(pry):1:in `fetch': key not found: :foo (KeyError)
    from (pry):1:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
#<Thread:0x000000011a2f7450 (pry):1 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
(pry):1:in `fetch': key not found: :foo (KeyError)
    from (pry):1:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
KeyError: key not found: :foo
```

Note that `.fetch` is being called on the empty hash `{}` (otherwise the error would be `undefined method 'fetch' for nil:NilClass`).

However, that can only be possible if there was context switching happening on the `sleep` line. I would expect that to happen because it's blocking IO, but sleep is **inside the mutex#synchronize** call. So how can that happen?

Notice that:

- The same mutex is effectively being shared by the threads (I confirmed with it's #object_id), since it's stored in a constant;
- The bug does not happen if the `sleep` method is removed;

However, what bugs me the most is that **the exception also isn't raised if I change the name of the instance variable inside `#build_series`**. What I mean is that this will NEVER raise:

```rb
class TestClass

  MUTEX = Mutex.new

  class << self

    def series
      @series ||= MUTEX.synchronize { @series || build_series }
    end

    def build_series
      @build_series = {}
      sleep 3
      @build_series = { foo: "bar" }
      @build_series
    end

  end

end
```

How come does this happen? Inside the `MUTEX.synchronize` block, `@series` should only be non-nil after the first thread releases the mutex lock, and that should only happen after `build_series` returns, at which point `@series` shouldn't be an empty hash anymore, and it should contain the `:foo` key.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.

The 10 threads start their journey.

The first one hits `#series`, checks that `@series` is nil, acquires the mutex lock and calls `build_series`, which sets `@series` to an empty hash and hits the sleep call.

A fraction of time later, the other threads hits `#series`, but at this point `@series` is already set, and that will be returned. They don't ever reach the `MUTEX.synchronize` call.

That's why changing the instance variable name in `build_series` fixes everything.

Comment: This is a classic [*Time-Of-Check to Time-Of-Use Race Condition*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use).